# Measurable decomposition of one set to construct another in measure space

Tags: measure-theory

Assume we are working in an arbitrary measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu).$

**Question 1:** Take any two measureable subsets $A$ and $B$ with equal measure. Is it possible to deconstruct one of those sets, e.g. into a partition of measureable sets, and then transform each piece of the partition in such a way as to preserve its measure and to be able to reconstruct the other set from the transformed partition?

**Question 2:** Under what conditions is the answer above "yes" in the likely case that it is at least sometimes "no"?

I'd love to see some references or a general argument/proof, however I would be thrilled to see examples or counter-examples as well. Just start with $\mathbb R.$ Can I take a fat Cantor set with measure $\epsilon$ and break it apart and shift/reflect each piece so as to reconstruct the set $[0,\epsilon]$ or $(0,\epsilon)$? Just take the regular Cantor set. Can I transform it into a singleton or the empty set? So "point removal" or "point addition" is measure preserving.

*Some other thoughts:* Maybe we need $X$ to have some sort of "spatial structure" so that for any $x,y\in X$ there is a measure-preserving operation $F$ such that $F(x)=y$ and that for any $A\in\Sigma$, $\mu(F(A))=\mu(A).$ I'm thinking along the lines of shifts, reflections and rotations in $\mathbb R^n,$ but maybe the idea "spatial structure" can be generalized to an arbitrary space that has measure-preserving transformations. Generally, we will want to disallow overlapping sufficiently, at least up to sets of measure zero, I presume.

So, more formally, the idea is that $\forall A,B\in\Sigma$ with $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$, we can find a disjoint partition of measureable sets $A=\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ and measure-preserving transformations $\{F_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ such that $F_\alpha(A_\alpha)=B_\alpha$ and $\{B_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ forms a disjoint partition of $B$.

Maybe it only works if the index set $I$ is countable, and thus only works on certain kinds of measurable sets. Intuitively it seems that any countable set can be transformed into any other countable set by just shifting each point individually (assuming a "shift" exists and is measure preserving in the particular space).

Comment: This is we’ll known ‘Banach-Tarski paradox’. You can search over internet about it.

Comment: As far as I know, the Banach-Tarski paradox has to do with deconstructing a measureable set into non-measureable pieces and transforming those so as to reconstruct a set of different measure. So the fact that the transforms are measure preserving is kind of meaningless there. I'm trying to keep everything measureable here. I've edited the post to clarify that.

Comment: The important question is "what counts a transformation?" Do you mean measure preserving maps?

Comment: @KyleGannon, yes, I suppose "measure preserving map" might be the proper, more general terminology.